# Samba with Windows AD sync, read only attribute not set

Tags: samba

Windows machines connecting to the Samba server are not able to set the read only flag. User do not get an error message setting the attribute. However, when you reopen the file properties, the read only attribute is unset again.

Setting the flag as file owner doesn`t make a difference.

```
[global]
# No .tld
workgroup = ERT
netbios name= ertdrp
name resolve order = bcast lmhosts host wins
# Active Directory System
security = ads
# With .tld
realm = ERT.LOCAL
# Just a member server
domain master = no
local master = no
preferred master = no
# Disable printing error log messages when CUPS is not installed.
printcap name = /etc/printcap
load printers = no
# Works both in samba 3.2 and 3.6.
idmap backend = tdb
idmap uid = 10000-99999
idmap gid = 10000-99999
# no .tld
idmap config ERT:backend = rid
idmap config ERT:range = 10000-9999
winbind enum users = yes
winbind enum groups = yes
# This way users log in with username instead of username@example.org
winbind use default domain = yes
# Inherit groups in groups
winbind nested groups = yes
winbind refresh tickets = yes
winbind offline logon = true
# Becomes /home/example/username
template homedir = /home/%D/%U
# No shell access
template shell = /bin/false
client use spnego = yes
client ntlmv2 auth = yes
encrypt passwords = yes
restrict anonymous = 2
log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log
log level = 3

[data]
comment = data
path = "/media/x"
valid users = ERT\xx, @ERT\gebruikers
force group = gebruikers
writable = yes
read only = no
force create mode = 0777
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
force directory mode = 0777
access based share enum = yes
hide unreadable = yes
```

Files and folders are all 777.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by allowing Windows ACL`s and applied the permissions from Windows.

I added this to my config

```
vfs objects = acl_xattr
map acl inherit = yes
store dos attributes = yes
```

And removed

```
#orce create mode = 0777
create mask = 0777
#directory mask = 0777
force directory mode = 0777
force group = Domeingebruikers
```